# Find tight bound of the recurrence equation

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations

> 9. (10 pts) Define
>    $$
>    f(n) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } n = 1 \\ 2f(\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor ) + n \lg n & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
>    $$

I'm not sure whether I'm correct...I used Master's Theorem for cases where n>1 to get theta(n(log^2(n))). Should I just ignore the case for n = 1? since 1 is smaller than nlog^2(n).

If possible, is there any other methods to find the tight bound of this piecewise function (besides Master Theorem) ?
Thank you.

Comment: If $n=1$ then $n\log^2(n)=0$.

Comment: In any case, the definition of $\theta$ notation only assumes the bounds hold for $n\ge n_0$, for some $n_0$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax instead of a photo. This makes it easier for future users to search for this problem if they have similar questions ^_^

Comment: Thank you @quasi !! My prof also gave a hint that the stopping condition of the recursion can be used as a proof.

Comment: Thank you @HallaSurvivor for the editing!! I'm still an amateur in using the MSE UI XD